# Standard inner product, change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question regarding the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined for two vectors $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ by $\langle v,w\rangle=\sum_i v_iw_i$. I know that this should be independent of the choice of basis, but I don't see how that's independent, if I choose a different basis the $v_i$ and $w_i$ will change. Let's say I compute this in a orthonormal basis $\langle v,w\rangle=\sum_i v_iw_i$ and then change the basis to a non-orthonormal basis: $\langle v,w\rangle=\sum_i v_i'w_i'$ in general $\sum_i v_i'w_i' \neq \sum_i v_iw_i$ .

Comment: Indeed the formula is not independent of the choice of basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner product **can be defined** in basis-independent way. That is $\langle v,w\rangle=|v|*|w|*cos(a)$.

This value can be calculated easily if you have coordinates of the vectors in some orthonormal basis. First you have to prove that inner product is linear, than you need to present each vector as a combination of basis vectors. It turns out that to calculate the inner product you do not have to calculate lengths of the vectors and measure the angle between them - just multiply coordinates!

And because the inner product definition can be basis-independent the result of the $\sum_i v_i w_i$ must be independent of basis (as long as basis is orthonormal).

Comment: Thanks! Great answer! Just what I was looking for!

Comment: @user3633438 The question is also great! Somehow when they teach what is inner product they do not bother to explain why is it important and why it is basis-independent.

Comment: How did you define $|v|$ or $\alpha$ in a basis-independent way?

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon I think that in "school" level there is no need (and impossible) to rigorously define these things. We have dots on the plane, we can measure distances between them, we can measure angles between lines. We also can choose frame of coordinates and use coordinates of dots to perform calculations - but dots and lines and angles are still the same, no matter are we using coordinates or not. Distances and angles are primary concepts on this level.
If you start with definition of vector space, then define Euclidian ones, ans so on.. But that's not what Luka asked about.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, that formula is not invariant under change of basis. The inner product is, but how you compute it is not. So when you change basis you need to change the formula to have the same inner product.